# fetching data from component in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hi i am sorry if this question is too basic. But I recently started learning React and NextJS. I am creating simple application that fetch some data and display it on Home page. I have two functions in my component file. I imported that component file in my index.js and using it as composition. The error says map is returning data of undefined.

```js
// Names.js Component

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const names = await prisma.name.findMany()

  return {
    props: {
      names
    }
  }
}

function Data({names}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {names.map((namelist) => (
          <li key={namelist.id}>{namelist.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}



export default Data

// Index.js
export default function Home() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Names />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: does the names variable exactly get the data after the request?

Comment: If i am using it in index.js file. then I can fetch names

Comment: I meant that from your request "const names = await prisma.name.findMany ()" data may not be included in the names variable.

Comment: you just need to return {names}; no need for `props` key

Comment: Can you try logging `names` inside `getStaticProps`. Might be issue that you are fetching correctly from `prisma` side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getStaticProps` can only be called from pages, not from components. You'll need to move it to `Index.js` (assuming that's under `/pages` folder).

```js
// Index.js
export default function Home({ names }) {
  return(
    <div>
      <Names names={names} />
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const prisma = new PrismaClient()
  const names = await prisma.name.findMany()

  return {
    props: {
      names
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// Names.js Component
function Data({ names }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {names.map((namelist) => (
          <li key={namelist.id}>{namelist.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Data
```